# ImportError: cannot import name UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How to fix,

```
2018-01-20 13:11:31,453 7023 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0
2018-01-20 13:11:31,453 7023 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /home//Documents/Client_Projects//od-config
2018-01-20 13:11:31,453 7023 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home//.local/share/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/home//Documents/Client_Projects//odoo/odoo/addons', u'/home//Documents/Client_Projects//odoo/addons', u'/home//Documents/Client_Projects//', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons']
2018-01-20 13:11:31,453 7023 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2018-01-20 13:11:31,459 7023 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8095
2018-01-20 13:12:05,033 7023 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2018-01-20 13:12:07,425 7023 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2018-01-20 13:12:08,938 7023 WARNING ? odoo.api: Deprecated method account_move_line.od_list_journals in module odoo.addons.bank_reconciliation_v10.models.account
2018-01-20 13:12:08,938 7023 WARNING ? odoo.api: Deprecated method account_move_line.book_bank_balance in module odoo.addons.bank_reconciliation_v10.models.account
2018-01-20 13:12:08,938 7023 WARNING ? odoo.api: Deprecated method account_move_line.od_list_accounts in module odoo.addons.bank_reconciliation_v10.models.account
2018-01-20 13:12:09,586 7023 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2018 13:12:09] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2018-01-20 13:12:09,591 7023 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 168, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home//Documents/Client_Projects/aasons/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 250, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home//Documents/Client_Projects/aasons/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home//Documents/Client_Projects/aasons/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home//Documents/Client_Projects/aasons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1307, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home//Documents/Client_Projects/aasons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1328, in load_addons
    m = __import__('odoo.addons.' + module)
  File "/home//Documents/Client_Projects/aasons/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 81, in load_module
    execfile(modfile, new_mod.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/l10n_fr_pos_cert/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..l10n_fr_certification.models.res_company import UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES
ImportError: cannot import name UNALTERABLE_COUNTRIES
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: 2 things if you want us to fix your Client Projects then provide us the code for your client projects :-) secondly i think your formatting should be improved before anyone wants to look more than 5 seconds at your question

Comment: @MehrdadEPI am getting this error while selecting database

Comment: @studioj I can't run the instance because while selecting the database I am getting this issue.

Comment: can you check if you have the proper add on installed for this odoo? Please check if there is a folder /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/l10n_fr_certification. In that folder you should find a models.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try reinstalling node modules**

```
sudo apt-get remove npm nodejs node less less­-plugin­-clean­-css
sudo apt-get purge 
sudo apt-get install npm nodejs node less less­-plugin­-clean­-css
sudo su odoo
cd ~
curl -L -o- https://github.com/creationix/nvm/raw/master/install.sh | bash

# to test nvm and list available versions
nvm ls-remote
# to list the presently installed verisons and active version
nvm list
# either use Latest LTS  or v4.4.7
nvm install --lts
nvm list
exit

sudo su odoo
nvm reinstall-packages

exit
sudo service odoo-server restart
# clear your browser cache.

sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
apt install nodejs-legacy
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/lessc /usr/bin/lessc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
apt-mark hold node-less
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the issue

- Download the latest odoo file from github

  https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/10.0
- Replace the addons file in "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo" with 
  latest addons from github.
- Restart odoo

  > sudo service odoo restart

Answer (score 0):

Some package would be missing.
Will check and revert.